# Question about an expectation

Tags: conditional-expectation, variance-decomposition

Let $x$ and $\gamma$ be vectors. Here it says that $$E[y-x'\gamma]^2 = E[(y-E[y|x])^2 + (E[y|x]-x'\gamma)^2]$$

However, I don't see why $$E[(y-E[y|x])(E[y|x]-x'\gamma)] = 0.$$

By the way, $E$ is the same as $E_{x,y}$ for all purposes. I wasn't getting this term to vanish.

And on a side note, how come we say that $\hat{\beta} = \beta + A\epsilon$ is a linear function of $\epsilon$? It can't be linear since $\hat{\beta} \neq T\epsilon$ for some linear map $T$...

Comment: Okay never mind the first part, this follows by conditioning on $x$. Still wondering about the linear part though...

Comment: Lots of people, me included, use "linear" to mean "affine" (linear + constant).

Answer (score 2):

Use the tower property to write the expectation as
$$
\mathrm{E}\big[\mathrm{E}[(y-\mathrm{E}[y\mid x])(\mathrm{E}[y\mid x]-x'\gamma)\mid x]\big].
$$
The term $\mathrm{E}[y\mid x]-x'\gamma$ is measurable with respect to (the sigma-algebra induced by) $x$ and hence can be 'pulled' out of the inner conditional expectation:
$$
\mathrm{E}\big[(\mathrm{E}[y\mid x]-x'\gamma)\mathrm{E}[y-\mathrm{E}[y\mid x]\mid x]\big].
$$
Then just note that this is zero since 
$$
\mathrm{E}[y-\mathrm{E}[y\mid x]\mid x]=\mathrm{E}[y\mid x]-\mathrm{E}[y\mid x]=0.
$$